# Valid Connection Information is Getting Denied

Tags: ftp, local-installation

I'm getting prompted to enter my FTP information (in this case, SFTP) for installing plugins/themes in Wordpress.  Problem is, I keep getting denied with valid SFTP credentials.

I have root access to my server as well.  RedHat 6.3, MySQL 5.1, PHP 5.3.3

For troubleshooting sake, all of Wordpress's directories are currently `chmod 777`

Every time I enter the login credentials that I'm SFTP'ing into the server with, I'm met with the error -

```
ERROR: There was an error connecting to the server, Please verify the settings are correct.
```

I've tried regular FTP, SFTP, creating new FTP users, using localhost, using the static address, about everything I could think of.

I've even gone as far as editing `wp-config.php` to include FTP info like so

```
/** FTP SETTINGS FOR AUTO-UPDATE */
define('FTP_HOST', 'Tried both static IP and localhost');
define('FTP_USER', 'user');
define('FTP_PASS', 'pass');
```

I can upload plugins and files manually through Filezilla or another client (using the SFTP credentials it is currently denying), but I'd like the ability to do one-click upgrades and installs.

I wouldn't think there is a firewall issue because Wordpress is installed on a localhost MySQL.  Pretty sure I didn't say that right.... but you get the idea.  I'm not leaving the box I'm on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you try http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ssh-sftp-updater-support/ ?  If that doesn't work you can do a quick code change to get the logs with which the developer of that plugin can use do more diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

Following up from retomate's answer, SSH SFTP Updater Support worked for me, the plugin adds the additional Connection Type options, I used the following settings:
[image]